# Databricks and Azure Files

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-files

I need to access [Azure Files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/) from [Azure Databricks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/databricks/). According to the documentation [Azure Blobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) are supported but I am need this code to work with Azure files:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = {"<conf-key>":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")})
```

or is there another way to mount/access [Azure Files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/) to/from a [Azure Databricks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/databricks/) cluster? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Azure, generally you can mount a file share of Azure Files to Linux via SMB protocol. And I tried to follow the offical tutorial [`Use Azure Files with Linux`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) to do it via create a notebook in Python to do the commands as below, but failed.

[image]

It seems that Azure Databricks does not allow to do that, even I searched about `mount NFS`, `SMB`, `Samba`, etc. in Databricks community that there is not any discussion.

So the only way to access files in Azure Files is to install the `azure-storage` package and directly to use Azure Files SDK for Python on Azure Databricks.

Comment: 1. You need to be root in order to mount
2. It's not practical to mount a share everytime a cluster starts
3. I guess I will need to switch to Azure blob in order to use Databricks.
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @Frank Sure, you need to switch to Azure Blob. I tried to mount file share via `sudo` as root and got the same error. For #2, the offical tutorial I linked introduces how to persistently mount via `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: I would not attempt to mount any storage directly without using dbutils (which does not support Azure Files). If you try to mount via fstab that will mount the storage on the driver node only. Assuming you want to run a spark workload you need the workers to have access to the storage. Consider using Azure Data Factory to move the files to blob/lake instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Install Library: azure-storage-file-share**
https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-share/

**#Upload to Azure File Share**

```
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareFileClient
 
file_client = ShareFileClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING", share_name="AZURE_STORAGE_FILE_SHARE_NAME", file_path="summary_uploaded.csv")
 
with open("/dbfs/tmp/summary_to_upload.csv", "rb") as source_file:
    file_client.upload_file(source_file)
```

**#Download from Azure File Share**

```
file_client = ShareFileClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING", share_name="AZURE_STORAGE_FILE_SHARE_NAME", file_path="summary_to_download.csv")
 
with open("/dbfs/tmp/summary_downloaded.csv", "wb") as file_handle:
    data = file_client.download_file()
    data.readinto(file_handle)
```

**Next steps:**

1. Define a new secret key in Azure Key Vault for holding the value for ‘conn_str’ (AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING).
   Key can be: az-storage-conn-string
2. Define a new secret key in Azure Key Vault for holding the value for ‘share_name’ (AZURE_STORAGE_FILE_SHARE_NAME).
   Key: az-storage-file-share
3. Read both of these keys from key vault and avoid hard-coding.