# Databricks: No module named azure.storage

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, fileshare

I was following the answer in this question [Load file from Azure Files to Azure Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59928574/load-file-from-azure-files-to-azure-databricks) to create the SAS token with the following code

```
# Create a client of Azure File Service as same as yours
from azure.storage.file import FileService

account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'
share_name = 'test'
directory_name = None
file_name = 'test.xlsx'

file_service = FileService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
```

But I got the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'
```

I already install the module with these commands

```
!pip install azure
!pip install azure-storage
!pip install azure-storage-file
```

And I installed the same modules into the cluster as you can see in the caption
[image]

None of the previous attempts was able to fix my "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'"

[image]
Does anyone have a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is located in another package: `azure.storage.file.fileservice` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.fileservice?view=azure-python)), so you need to write:

```py
from azure.storage.file.fileservice import FileService
```

Comment: I am still wondering why but it works, thanks!!